# Was Darth Maul part of the Separatist movement?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, the-phantom-menace, darth-maul, trade-federation

In Star Wars Battlefront II (2005 and 2017), we see Darth Maul in the side of the Separatist. In the Phantom Menace, The Confederacy of Independent Systems or the Separatist is not yet  formed only the Trade Federation is seen.However,in the next movie(Attack of the Clones up until Revenge of the Sith),The Trade Federation is now in league with the CIS. During the battle of Naboo, The Dark Lord of the Sith Darth Sidious sent his apprentice, Darth Maul to assist the Neimoidians Viceroy Nute Gunray and Rune Haako. So let's compare the villains in Star Wars with their association in every factions.

- Chancellor Palpatine/Darth Sidious/Emperor Palpatine - (Republic as Chancellor of the Republic,Separatist as Darth Sidious, Empire as Emperor)
- Count Dooku/Darth Tyranus - Republic(secretly) and Separatist
- General Grievous - Separatist
- Jango Fett - Separatist
- Boba Fett - Empire
- Grand Moff Tarkin - Empire
- Darth Vader - Empire

---

So looking at those individuals, Darth Maul is the only villain that doesn't have a military faction.*Which makes me wonder if he's included in the Separatist Movement.Despite he is just assisting the Trade Federation during the Battle of Naboo.* Not to mention that every apprentice of Darth Sidious has a military group like for instance: Dooku/Tyranus to the CIS and Vader to the Empire.

Comment: His only goal is the destruction of the Jedi and his only loyalty is to Sidious.

Comment: And after his first 'death' he basically just becomes a super gangster with allegiance only to himself, and a pathological hatred of Obi-wan

Comment: Are you sure Jango Fett is a Separatist? I thought he was a free agent willing to sell his services to anybody on any side of any conflict.

Comment: @RichS as far as I'm concerned he is. Like Boba Fett to the Empire. Jango fett serves his loyalty in both Separatists and Republic (secretly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, he was not

The first reason is in your own question - the Separatist movement was formed after Maul's demise on Naboo, with formal leader Count Dooku aka Darth Tyrannus, who was Maul's successor as Sith apprentice to Darth Sidious.

At the time of *Attack Of the Clones*, Maul was incapable of anything, and presumed dead. During the Clone Wars, Maul was clearly pursuing his own goals, mainly revenge against Obi-Wan. But he was not involved in political or military operations on the large scale.

Second is that Maul was not into politics. He was a warrior, doing Sidious' dirty work, but not really suitable for negotiations, bargaining and other things that Dooku was better suited for.

For the game reasons however, Maul could be considered as part of the Separatists army, because it was based on the same droid army he was associated with in the *Phantom Menace*.

Comment: It makes sense Why Maul is part of the Separatist in the games. But in canon, Maul seems to be an assassin not a leader. That role belng to Dooku/Tyranus. However, I wonder if Darth Maul was never defeated during the Naboo crisis and if Dooku wasn't turned to the dark side  would he be the Separatist Leader?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar good point. I think that Dsrth Sidious would orchestrate his demise and find a different apprentice anyway. He needed a more able one, than a brutal assassin.
Also, in the Legends, Sidious orchestrates the whole sequence of events from the birth of Anakin Skywalker, to bring him to the Dark Side, as the Sith believed that he would tip the balance to ensure their endless reign.

Comment: slr, then who could that be instead of Dooku

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar perhaps someone we do not know. There was a number of Jedi who left the order, each for their own reasons, and all were unhappy with certain aspects of the Order. Given Sidious's manipulation skills, he would find a capable apprentice.