# When did the Separatist Movement start within the Galactic Republic?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

When and how did the Separatist Movement begin?

I am asking about the separatists before they officially became the Confederacy of Independent Systems. In the second movie, the separatists have gathered on Geonosis before they have announced their intentions to leave the Galactic Republic. The war begins and now the public knows that many systems want to leave the republic. Surprise! For that to happen, they must have been plotting this long before.

An answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217257/was-darth-maul-part-of-the-separatist-movement?rq=1) says the Separatist Movement began after Darth Maul died, but does not say exactly when or how.

Please answer with quotes from canon sources.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be hinted at in canon sources and mentioned in Legend sources that for some time, outer worlds were not happy in how they were being treated by the increasingly corrupt Senate.  But there is no actual canon portrayal of how the separatist movement got started.

I believe once the Trade Federation's invasion of Naboo failed, and with Dooku replacing the defeated Darth Maul as the apprentice of Sidious, active manipulation of disenfranchised worlds towards separatism began as early as 32 BBY, culminating in the formation of the Confederacy of Independent Systems in 24 BBY.

Comment: Any references for "active manipulation...began as early as 32BBY"?

Comment: No, as stated I could not find any canon sources for this information.  It's my theory.  The Battle of Naboo occurred in 32 BBY.

Comment: whenever it started, it feels certain to think that Palpatine was behind it